# Not able to connect MySQL database with Eclipse Neon

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, mysql-connector

I want to learn BIRT reporting in Eclipse Neon on my MacOS.

Following the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhLrdX7Kaos) steps "Select a Data Source Type or Choose a Connection Profile" step and then clicking next button, but next doesn't do any action, so I thought let's try to connect to database using Eclipse' Database Development perspective, so I performed:

**1.**[image]

**2.**[image]

**3.**[image]

**4.**[image]

**5.** [image]

But when I try to test connections I get this error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Ping server job".
>   java/sql/SQLException
>   [image]

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Did you try URL: as `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306`

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes same error

Comment: you might have already tried, are you able to connect via workbench?

Comment: also try selecting driver 5.0 instead of 5.1

Comment: @sidgate Just tried both suggestions [I am able to access DB through MySQL Workbench] but still getting same error! I have two Eclipse versions on my machine but they are in different paths, does that matter/will it create problem?

Comment: Have you installed a MySQL DB on your computer and is it running?

Comment: @Jens Yes and I have database schemas that I can access through terminal and MySQL Workbench